# Compiling an ATL DLL in 32 bits and 64 bits

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linker

I have a solution under Visual Studio 2019 that is composed of two projects:

- one win32 project which the name is projectX and the corresponding generated lib file is ProjectX.lib
- one ATL project which the name is projectX_ATL and the corresponding generated lib file is ProjectX_ATL.lib

While compiling in debug mode x86 works fine, the compilation in Debug x64 failed with the following error message:
`LINK : fatal error LNK1104: impossible to open the file 'C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Documents\PRO\PRICING NATION\SHAITAN\Debug.obj'`

This means at the link step of the compilation, VS is looking for a missing file to link this file Debug.obj doesn't exist at all in any folder of the solution...

How to solve this compilation error ?

Comment: If you open up the project properties, under general, is the intermediate directory the same for both 32 & 64 bit?  If it is then the object files are overwriting each other.  Set it to something like $(Configuration)$(PlatformArchitecture)\ or $(PlatformName) or something unique

Comment: Or maybe the onedrive directory only contains softlinks or so?